# Store value in memory address using Assembly with 68HC11

Tags: memory, assembly, store, 68hc11

I´m new to assembly programming so I´m using THRSim11 to program some assembly examples.
I´m trying to store a value in memory address $0142 but it seems the value in this memory address doesn´t change.

```
LDAA    #$00
STAA    $0142
```

I first load Acc A with 00 value and then try to store this value to memory address $0142 but it will not change value from $FF.
If I do this with address $40 it works...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[THRSim11](http://www.hc11.demon.nl/thrsim11/info.htm) simulates only memory in the ranges $0000-$00ff and $ff00-$ffff, unless you have the licensed version. Therefore you cannot use the address $0142 in the unlicensed version.

Comment: Hi Sami, thanks for your answer.How can I license the sotfware? Making a donation?